# ORA-01722: invalid number Error - 1

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm stuck and can't see what the problem is.

I created a procedure with some logic stuff and it compiled successfully, but when I call it in a trigger on my table, it fails with `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Here is the procedure:

```
create or replace Procedure Check_Plants_Fields(  
    field_id                 IN               number ,
    farmer_name              IN               varchar2,
    planting_date            IN               date DEFAULT sysdate,
    planting_amount          IN               number,
    plant_type               IN               number)    
IS
   l_plant_type XXLA_PLANTS_TYPE.PLANT_TYPE%type;
   l_number_of_months  XXLA_PLANTS_SUPPLIERS.NUMBER_MONTHS_TO_CUT%type;    
   cursor c1 is
       SELECT PLANT_TYPE , AMOUNT_
       FROM XXLA_PLANTS_TYPE
       WHERE PLANT_ID = plant_type;  
   cursor c2 is
       SELECT to_number(MOD(Round(DBMS_RANDOM.Value(1, 8)), 9) + 1)
       FROM DUAL;
BEGIN
   open c1;
   open c2;
   fetch c2 into l_number_of_months;
   if c1 %notfound then
       close c1;
       dbms_output.put_line('You dont have this type, please supply it to your store . ' || '     ' || 'thanx.'); 
   end if;
   for i in (SELECT PLANT_TYPE , AMOUNT_
            FROM XXLA_PLANTS_TYPE
            WHERE PLANT_ID = plant_type) 
   LOOP
       if i.AMOUNT_ < 20 then
           dbms_output.put_line(i.AMOUNT_ ||' AMOUNT_: '|| i.AMOUNT_);
           UPDATE XXLA_PLANTS_SUPPLIERS
           SET supplier_id = supplier_id_seq.nextval;
           INSERT INTO XXLA_PLANTS_SUPPLIERS
               (supplier_id, supplier_name, number_months_to_cut, date_,amount, price_in_KG)
           VALUES (supplier_id_seq.nextval, 'Benefits etc',l_number_of_months ,sysdate+1, 80 + i.AMOUNT_,'500$');     
        end if;
   END LOOP i;
   commit;
   close c2;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered,- '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- -->'||SQLERRM );
END;
```

And here is the trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER xxbefor_insert_plants
BEFORE INSERT ON  XXLA_PLANT_FIELDS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    Check_Plants_Fields(:NEW.field_id, :NEW.farmer_name, :NEW.planting_date, :NEW.planting_amount, :NEW.plant_type);
END;
```

Here is the insert that executes the trigger that calls the procedure, but it errors when I run it.

```
INSERT INTO XXLA_PLANT_FIELDS
(field_id, FARMER_NAME,planting_date,planting_amount,plant_type )
VALUES
(4, 'Test1',sysdate,8,1 (because this parameter it should work its under 20 ));
```

Comment: `create or replace TRIGGER befor_insert_plants BEFORE INSERT ON XXLA_PLANT_FIELDS REFERENCING NEW as NEW OLD as OLD FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN Check_Plants_Fields(:NEW.field_id, :NEW.farmer_name, :NEW.planting_date, :NEW.planting_amount, :NEW.plant_type); END;

the insert to table that need execute the logic in the proccedur but i have error .... anyone ?

INSERT INTO XXLA_PLANT_FIELDS (field_id, FARMER_NAME,planting_date,planting_amount,plant_type ) VALUES (4, 'Test1',sysdate,8,1(because this parameter it should work its under 20 ));

Thanx a lot for every one . `

Comment: You say you have an error... what error? Thanks for providing the procedure, trigger and insert statement, but unfortunately your test case is missing the DDL to create the table, along with the details of the issue you're getting, so we can't help you. Please edit your question to add in more details. Thanks.

Comment: What is the datatype of `price_in_kg`? If it's a number, you can't put `'500$'` into it. By the way, that exception handler is worse than useless. You can improve exception handling by removing it. And formatting your code neatly can often reveal things about the structure that help debug issues.

Comment: What is `(because this parameter it should work its under 20 )`? If that is part of the actual insert then obviously it is not valid SQL.

Comment: I suspect the error tells you a lot about why the `INSERT` fails. Also, what possible purpose does the procedure's `WHEN OTHERS` exception catch serve? I can't unsee that, now. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelO'Neill - If you're offended by a posted piece of code by all means comment and suggest how the OP could improve it. But please don't edit the OP's post to remove or change its functionality.

Comment: @APC Fair enough. I will proceed in the future accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`ORA-01722: invalid number` is quite a simple error to understand. It means you are attempting to cast a string to a number datatype but the operation fails because the string contains non-numeric characters.

So what this means is that somewhere in your procedure you have a implicit type conversion. You haven't provided the description of the tables so we can't tell you where the problem happens. You'll have to discover it for yourself.

Two places where it might be:

- `WHERE PLANT_ID = plant_type` if `XXLA_PLANTS_TYPE.PLANT_ID` is not
  numeric
- `VALUES (... '500$');` if
  `XXLA_PLANTS_SUPPLIERS.PRICE_IN_KG` is not numeric

Incidentally, if you removed that pointless exception handler you would get the default error stack. That would tell you **the starting line number** of the failing statement, which would really remove a lot of the guesswork from the exercise.

Comment: Thank you all for help, god bless you guys